# asp.net code within aspx file between quotation marks doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, html, inline

This is something simple I guess, but I'm stuck with this and can't work further.

I have the following code:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbxLevel_s" runat="server" Text='<%=this.rs.get("workshop")%>' />
```

the method between `Text=` returns a string.

But what I get on the page is `<%=this.rs.get("workshop")%>` and not the string that should be returned.

This same method can be used on places where there are no quotation marks. Any help?

Comment: Is your checkbox within the "form runat=server" tag?

Answer (score 1):

The quotation marks aren't the problem.  The problem is that the control is a server-side control.  You can either look in to data binding like James Johnson suggested or you can put this in your code behind:

> `cbxLevel_s.Text = this.rs.get("workshop");`